# Reading from Input Files in Java

Tags: java, file-io, io

I've been trying to figure out how to do this code, but can't figure out how to change my current code to work.

The problem reads:

> Write a program to read an integer N (2 <= N <= 30) from an input filename “input5_01.txt” and then write a function to create an N x N matrix with random integers from the range [10, 99]. Output that matrix to the
>   output filename “output5_01.txt”

Currently, here's my code:

```
public static final int UPPER = 99, LOWER = 10;

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    int n = 5;
    int[][] arr = new int[n][n];
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(new File("input5_01.txt"));

      //read in an int (n) from input file
    while (inputFile.hasNext()) {
        if (inputFile.hasNextInt() >= 2 && inputFile.hasNextInt() <= 30) {
            n = inputFile.nextInt();
        } else {
            inputFile.next();
        }
    }

     //assigning random numbers to array
    Random rand = new Random();
    for (int r = 0; r < arr.length; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < arr[0].length; c++) {
            arr[r][c] = rand.nextInt(UPPER - LOWER + 1) + LOWER;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Really, the only problem I have is:

```
if(inputFile.hasNextInt() >= 2 && inputFile.hasNextInt() <= 30)
```

What can I do to make this work?

Comment: Are you getting an error? What is happening with your current code?

Comment: As a best practice, specify a character set: `new Scanner(new File("input5_01.txt"), "UTF-8");`

Comment: [how-to-use-java-util-scanner-to-correctly-read-user-input-from-system-in](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26446599/how-to-use-java-util-scanner-to-correctly-read-user-input-from-system-in)

Answer (score 0):

As per the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt--), `hasNextInt()` returns a boolean, denoting if there is another integer value or not within the stream, it does not return the value of the next integer. Thus, this section:

```
while(inputFile.hasNext()){
  if(inputFile.hasNextInt() >= 2 && inputFile.hasNextInt() <= 30)
    n = inputFile.nextInt();   
  else
    inputFile.next();
}
```

Would need to read something like so:

```
int nextInt = -1;
boolean intFound = false;

while(inputFile.hasNext()){
  if(inputFile.hasNextInt()) {
      nextInt = inputFile.nextInt();
      if((nextInt >= 2) && (nextInt <= 30) {
          intFound = true;
          break;
      }
  }   
}

if(intFound) {
     ... //Populate your matrix according to the value of nextInt
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your input file will have only `ints` then I believe this should also work:

```
while(inputFile.hasNextInt()){
  int nextIntValue = inputFile.nextInt();
  if(nextIntValue >= 2 && nextIntValue <= 30) {
    n = nextIntValue ;   break;
  }
  else
    inputFile.next();
}
```

It will also avoid unnecessary calls.