# What's the best way to read input in Java, especially for consecutive strings? I don't know when to use next() and nextLine()

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, nosuchelementexception, inputmismatchexception

I'm getting this error in a really simple code and I am not able to figure it out.

Also, please suggest what is the best way to read two consecutive strings, like in this case. I face InputMismatchException and I think that it could be the cause.

it's strange that the code fails to accept the integer too. I'm getting an exception while reading the integer.

I'm not sure when to use Scanner.next() and Scanner.nextLine().

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Customer
{
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String city;
    private double salary;

    Customer(){}

    Customer(int id, String name, String city, double salary)
    {
        this.id=id;
        this.name=name;
        this.city=city;
        this.salary=salary;
    }

    public int getId(){
        return id;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public String getCity(){
        return city;
    }

    public double getSalary(){
        return salary;
    }

    public void setId(int id){
        this.id=id;
    }

    public void setName(String name){
        this.name=name;
    }

    public void setCity(String city){
        this.city=city;
    }

    public void setSalary(double salary){
        this.salary=salary;
    }
}

public class Solution{

     public static void main(String []args){

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        Customer c = new Customer();

        int id = in.nextInt();
        String name = in.next();
        String city = in.next();
        double sal = in.nextDouble();

        c.setId(id);
        c.setName(name);
        c.setCity(city);
        c.setSalary(sal);

        System.out.println(c.getId() + " " + c.getName() + " " + c.getCity() + " " + c.getSalary());
     }
}
```

Input

```
1
ABC
MH
2000.25
```

Stack Trace

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
    at Solution.main(Solution.java:61)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use java.util.Scanner to correctly read user input from System.in and act on it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26446599/how-to-use-java-util-scanner-to-correctly-read-user-input-from-system-in-and-act)

Comment: The only errors I got were compiling errors and that's because I directly copied and pasted it into my compiler. In other words, I found 0 errors in your code.

Comment: For some reason, it's now working. I used next() and it accepted the input properly. With nextLine(), I'm getting InputMismatchException. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

`java.util.Scanner.next();` returns a word. i.e. read until seeing a newline character or space.

`java.util.Scanner.nextLine();` returns a line. i.e. read an entire line.

Both return strings.

If you want to read multiple Strings simultaneously, use `.nextLine();`, however `nextLine()` and other methods of reading have a conflict.

i.e. in this code

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
int A = sc.nextInt();
String S = sc.nextLine();
```

S will be an empty string. You can solve this by adding another `.nextLine()` in the program to swallow the newLine character. Some details are in the comments.

Comment: The problem still continues. I'm getting an exception while reading the integer.

Comment: Edit your question to include your input.

Comment: It doesn't accept any input. The exception is thrown, on executing.

Comment: I said include your input. I want to see if your input is wrong or some magical part of your code. Input order: **Integer, String, (seperated by spaces or newline characters) String, Double**