# How to read only one value with Scanner (Java)?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have multiple Scanner methods to save input, but when I execute the code and enter for example "word 5", the Scanner reads input for the next Scanner method as well. How can I stop that?

```
    ...
    correctInput = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < runnI; i++) {
        System.out.println(".....");
        array1[i] = sc.next();

        System.out.println(".....");
        do {
            try {
                array2[i] = sc.nextDouble();
                correctInput= false;
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("Wrong");
                sc.next();
            }
        } while (correctInput);
    }
```

Comment: Does it actually print "Wrong?"

Comment: No, it simply goes on with the code, but it doesn't ask the second input... sc.next should be for "word 5" and sc.nextDouble for another number

Comment: You set `array1[i]  = sc.next()` so I think that consumes `word`, leaving `5` to be consumed by the call to `sc.nextDouble().`

Comment: Yes and that's the problem. "word 5" should be set for array1[]

Comment: The default delimiter for `Scanner` is whitespace, so `sc.next()` will stop at the space after `word`. If you want it to read the whole line, you can call `nextLine`, or, if your input uses some other delimiter (maybe tab or comma) then call `useDelimiter`.

Comment: nextLine doesn't work either, when I do this, it just prints the two "......"s and goes on with the code

Comment: Is there actually a line ending? You may need to add one to the end of your input if it's not there.

Comment: How can I add such a line ending?

Comment: Not sure what your input *is* but if it's a string you could just do `someString + '\n'`.

Comment: This answer has some good points about how Scanner works. Hope it's helpful! https://stackoverflow.com/a/26446609/11226302

Answer (score 0):

So guys, I found out that it works, when I write `sc.nextLine()` before the first `System.out.println()` and `array1[i] = sc.nextLine()` after it