# How to handle weird input using scanner in java

Tags: java, oop, arraylist, switch-statement

I am working on code in which I am making an application that stores contacts by asking the user particular choice about operations he or she wants to perform like querying, storing, adding a contact, etc.

Below is sub-part of my code, I am actually trying to bug the issue when the user enters a wrong choice. What I mean to say is, if a user enters a non-numeric character, it should ask for the choice again,

```
package com.vakhariaKathan;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main
{
    private static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    private static MobilePhone mobilePhone = new MobilePhone();
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int choice;
        boolean quit = false;
        System.out.println("Hey there! :),\nI am your Mobile Phone,");
        printInstructions();
        while(!quit)
        {
            System.out.print("Enter choice: ");
            if(!scanner.hasNextInt())
            {
                System.out.println("You entered something bad ");
                scanner.nextLine();
                continue;
            }
            choice = scanner.nextInt();scanner.nextLine();
            switch (choice)
            {
                case 0:
                    printInstructions();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    mobilePhone.printContacts();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    handleAdditionOfContact();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.print("Enter contact name to be changed: ");
                    mobilePhone.modifyContact(scanner.nextLine());
                    break;
                case 4:
                    System.out.println("Enter any name of the following you want to delete.");
                    mobilePhone.showContactNames();
                    mobilePhone.removeContact(scanner.nextLine());
                    break;
                case 5:
                    quit = true;
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Enter a valid choice!");
                    break;
            }

        }

    }

    private static void printInstructions()
    {
        System.out.println("Currently i can do following operations.");
        System.out.println("0.Print instructions.");
        System.out.println("1.Show list of contacts.");
        System.out.println("2.Add Contact.");
        System.out.println("3.Modify a contact.");
        System.out.println("4.Delete Contact.");
        System.out.println("5.Quit");
    }

    //to handle addition of contact
    private static void handleAdditionOfContact()
    {
        String[] output = takeInput();
        mobilePhone.addContact(output[0],output[1]);
    }

    //Method to take user input
    private static String[] takeInput()
    {
        String name,contact;
        System.out.print("Enter name of the Contact: ");
        name = handleEmptyEntry("Name");
        if(mobilePhone.doesExist(name))
        {
            System.out.println("That contact already exists.\nTry a different name");
            name = handleEmptyEntry("Name");
        }
        System.out.print("Enter contact number for " + name + ": ");
        contact = handleEmptyEntry("contact");
        return new String[] {name,contact};
    }
    //function to handle empty entry
    private static String handleEmptyEntry(String fieldName)
    {
        String in = scanner.nextLine();
        while (in.isBlank())
        {
            System.out.printf("%s field cannot be empty ‼\nEnter again:",fieldName);
            in = scanner.nextLine();

        }
        return in;
    }

}
```

**There are mainly two scenarios:**

1)It works fine if a user enters a wrong character without hitting the enter key.
2)But when the user enters a new line and then enters a wrong character, it shows some weird behaviors.
Below are the outputs showing  both cases.

```
Hey there! :),
I am your Mobile Phone,
Currently i can do following operations.
0.Print instructions.
1.Show list of contacts.
2.Add Contact.
3.Modify a contact.
4.Delete Contact.
5.Quit
Enter choice: p
You entered something bad 
Enter choice: 

i
You entered something bad 
Enter choice: You entered something bad 
Enter choice: You entered something bad 
Enter choice:
```

***Will be pleased to have a detailed explanation!***

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use java.util.Scanner to correctly read user input from System.in and act on it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26446599/how-to-use-java-util-scanner-to-correctly-read-user-input-from-system-in-and-act)

Answer (score 0):

If you have written `scanner.next()` then you wouldn't have faced this issue but when you write `scanner.nextLine()` you faced this behaviour because before entering your non numberic value you pressed two times enter and then entered the non numeric value. So you got `You entered something bad` 3 times. Two times for the enter you pressed and one time for non-numeric value. This happens because newline character remains in the buffer and when you enter non-numeric value it reads all of them and print `You entered something bad`.

So if you press enter 5 times and then enter non-numeric value you'll get `You entered something bad` 6 times printed.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more on working of scanner.next() and scanner.nextLine() and its relation with the input buffer?